# To which part of speech belong 〜とはいえ and 〜というものの, and as what part of sentence are they usually used?

Tags: grammar

I came across `〜とはいえ` and `〜というものの`. They seem to be fixed expressions but I am not quite sure which part of speech they can be re-analysed as.

Answer (score 1):

You can check a Japanese dictionary.

They are called 連語 (phrase or idiom) when they are used in these forms:

> 1. Aとはいえ、B。
> 2. Aというものの、B。

“とはいえ” = 助詞 “と” + 助詞 “は” + 已然形 of 動詞 “言う”

“というものの” = 助詞 “と” + 連用形 of 動詞 “言う” + 名詞 “もの” + 助詞 “の”

They are called 接続詞 (conjunction) when they are used in these forms:

> 1. A。とはいえ、B。
> 2. B。というものの、B。

Comment: He was asking what they would be classified as if they were reanalyzed as single units, not how to break them down.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Thanks. I've updated my answer.